# how to custom filter in configure file for boost log?

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I had customized one sink with configure file, but the customized filter can't compile success with error:

unexpected character in the end of line.

it is caused by "" in ini. so how to solve it?

if I remove the last line ,it is ok.

configure file content sample.

```
Destination = "TextFile"
FileName = "ModuleOne_%3N.log"
AutoFlush = true
Filter=expr::attr<string>("Channel") == "module one"
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter="%Channel% contains \"MySink1\" and %Severity% > info " is ok.
and make sure before read configure:

register all the needed attribute ,what's more some types logger had register channel.